# Configure postgres database on a docker-compose first build for "background_tasks" use

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker-compose, background-task

I have a Django project that works great. The database is not registered in the repository.
So when I do a docker-compose up from scratch, the project can't find the tables corresponding to "background tasks"...

Task is refered in urls.py por immediate read on django project start.

What would be the way to launch the project without previously editing the code calls to this table?

docker-compose:

```
  version: '3'

  services:
    db:
      image: postgres
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
      volumes:
        - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    web:
      build: .
      command: bash -c "
        python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        & python manage.py migrate
        & python manage.py process_tasks"
      volumes:
        - .:/code
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
        - "5555:5555"
      depends_on:
        - db
```

Log error:

```
db_1   | 2020-10-16 11:48:35.090 UTC [32] ERROR:  relation "background_task" does not exist at character 24
db_1   | 2020-10-16 11:48:35.090 UTC [32] STATEMENT:  SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "background_task" WHERE "background_task"."verbose_name" = 'zmq_puller' LIMIT 1
db_1   | 2020-10-16 11:48:35.090 UTC [33] ERROR:  relation "background_task" does not exist at character 24
db_1   | 2020-10-16 11:48:35.090 UTC [33] STATEMENT:  SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "background_task" WHERE "background_task"."verbose_name" = 'zmq_puller' LIMIT 1
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
web_1  |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
web_1  | psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "background_task" does not exist
web_1  | LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "background_task" WHERE "background_t...
web_1  |                                ^
web_1  |
web_1  |
web_1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
web_1  |
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/code/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
web_1  |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
web_1  | psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "background_task" does not exist
web_1  | LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "background_task" WHERE "background_t...
web_1  |                                ^
web_1  |
web_1  |
web_1  | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
web_1  |
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/code/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
web_1  |     main()
web_1  |   File "/code/manage.py", line 18, in main
web_1  |     main()
web_1  |   File "/code/manage.py", line 18, in main
web_1  |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
web_1  |     utility.execute()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
web_1  |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
web_1  |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
web_1  |     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
web_1  |     res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 75, in handle
web_1  |     self.check(databases=[database])
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 392, in check
web_1  |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
web_1  |     all_issues = checks.run_checks(
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
web_1  |     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
web_1  |     return check_resolver(resolver)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
web_1  |     return check_method()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 408, in check
web_1  |     utility.execute()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
web_1  |     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
web_1  |         self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
web_1  |
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
web_1  |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 368, in execute
web_1  |     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
web_1  |         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)self.check()
web_1  |
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 392, in check
web_1  |     all_issues = checks.run_checks(
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
web_1  |     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
web_1  |     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
web_1  |         return check_resolver(resolver)return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
web_1  |
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
web_1  |     return check_method()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 408, in check
web_1  |     for pattern in self.url_patterns:
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
web_1  |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
web_1  |     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
web_1  |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
web_1  |     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
web_1  |       File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
web_1  | return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
web_1  |   File "/code/drf_accordion/urls.py", line 45, in <module>
web_1  |   File "/code/drf_accordion/urls.py", line 45, in <module>
web_1  |     if not Task.objects.filter(verbose_name="zmq_puller").exists():
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 809, in exists
web_1  |     return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 535, in has_results
web_1  |     return compiler.has_results()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1126, in has_results
web_1  |     return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
web_1  |     cursor.execute(sql, params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
web_1  |     return super().execute(sql, params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
web_1  |     return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
web_1  |     return executor(sql, params, many, context)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
web_1  |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
web_1  |     if not Task.objects.filter(verbose_name="zmq_puller").exists():
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 809, in exists
web_1  |         return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 535, in has_results
web_1  | raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value    return compiler.has_results()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1126, in has_results
web_1  |
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
web_1  |     return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
web_1  |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
web_1  | django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "background_task" does not exist
web_1  | LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "background_task" WHERE "background_t...
web_1  |                                ^
web_1  |
web_1  |     cursor.execute(sql, params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
web_1  |     return super().execute(sql, params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
web_1  |     return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
web_1  |     return executor(sql, params, many, context)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
web_1  |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
web_1  |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
web_1  |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
web_1  | django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "background_task" does not exist
web_1  | LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "background_task" WHERE "background_t...
```

Thanks por read!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added `background_task` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`: https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks/blob/master/docs/index.rst#installation

Comment: Added yes, task works, is when launch docker from scratch withotut commentd task lines on urls.py... goona see the order in installed apps

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run the server after applying the migrations.
**Try changing this**.

```
version: '3'
    ...
    web:    
        build: .
        command: bash -c "    
        python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        & python manage.py migrate
        & python manage.py process_tasks"
     ...
```

**To this**.

```
version: '3'.  
    ...
    web:    
      build: .    
      command: bash -c "
        python manage.py migrate
        & python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        & python manage.py process_tasks"
     ...
```